# Powershell CSV Output Issue

Tags: powershell, csv, wmi

Can anyone assist my with explanation as to why I get System.String[] as my Gateway output in the CSV file but it works fine in the ISE view/window.

```
$testcomputers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users2\101.txt'
$exportLocation = 'C:\Users2\PingResults.csv'

# Test connection to each computer before getting the inventory info
foreach ($computer in $testcomputers) {
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -count 1){
    Add-Content -value $computer -path C:\Users2\OnlineComputers.txt
  }else{
    Add-Content -value $computer -path C:\Users2\OfflineComputers.txt
  }
}

#Specify the list of PC names in the line below
$ArrComputers =  Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users2\OnlineComputers.txt'

Clear-Host
foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers)
{
    $computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer
    $computerBIOS = get-wmiobject Win32_BIOS -Computer $Computer
    $computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $Computer
    $computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer
    $computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter drivetype=3
    $computerGateway = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $Computer -Filter “IPEnabled=TRUE”
        write-host "System Information for: " $computerSystem.Name -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
        "-------------------------------------------------------"
        "Manufacturer: " + $computerSystem.Manufacturer
        "Model: " + $computerSystem.Model
        "Serial Number: " + $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
        "CPU: " + $computerCPU.Name
        "HDD Capacity: "  + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB"
        "HDD Space: " + "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size) + " Free (" + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/1GB) + "GB)"
        "RAM: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB"
        "Operating System: " + $computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
        "User logged In: " + $computerSystem.UserName
        "Last Reboot: " + $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime)
        "Gateway: " + $computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway
        ""
        "-------------------------------------------------------"

#Build the CSV file
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name
    'Manufacturer' = $computerSystem.Manufacturer
    'Model' = $computerSystem.Model
    'Service Tag' = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
    'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)
    'HDDSize' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB)
    'HDDFree' = "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size)
    'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption
    'SP' = $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
    'User' = $computerSystem.UserName
    'Last_Reboot' = $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime)
    'Gateway' = $computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway
    } 

#Export the fields you want from above in the specified order
$csvObject | Select PCName, Manufacturer, Model, OS, SerialNumber, CPU, Ram, User, Last_Reboot, HDDSize, HDDFree, Gateway | Export-Csv 'C:\Users2\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Here is the ISE output

```
System Information for:  WS101161
-------------------------------------------------------
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Model: OptiPlex 5070
Serial Number: 7HF8T13
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9500 CPU @ 3.00GHz
HDD Capacity: 237.96GB
HDD Space: 67.87% Free (161.51GB)
RAM: 15.79GB
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Service Pack: 0
User logged In: 
Last Reboot: 04/28/2022 17:40:52
Gateway: 10.170.1.250
-------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is the CSV output (User being empty is okay, nobody is signed into this PC at the moment)

```
"PCName","Manufacturer","Model","OS","SerialNumber","CPU","RAM","User","Last_Reboot","HDDSize","HDDFree","Gateway"
"WS101161","Dell Inc.","OptiPlex 5070","Microsoft Windows 10 Pro",,"Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9500 CPU @ 3.00GHz","15.79",,"4/28/2022 5:40:52 PM","237.96","67.87%","System.String[]"
```

Thank you for the assistance!

asdasdasd

Comment: By default, that class property returns `string[]` even if it is 1 element. You can cast `[string]` to it tho which should solve the problem

Comment: By the way, `Test-Connection` (ICMP) is not a reliable source of information to tell you if can actually establish a WinRM connection with a remote host.

Comment: Hello Santiago, nice to see you again, I hope to have the ability to hover around here and moderate and answer the forums like you do.  I don't exactly understand 100%, can you elaborate a little more?  Thank you

Comment: Interesting, can you recommend a preferred method I can learn about?

Comment: please post the CSV output ... not the MSExcel display after importing that CSV.

Comment: for just getting the info on a set of systems, DO NOT iterate thru the list of systems ... instead, use `Invoke-Command` with a scriptblock and a list of systems as parameters. that will run the scriptblocks on the targets & return the resulting objects. here is an example of the idea >>> basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH

Comment: Santiago is this what you are talking about? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convert-string?view=powershell-5.1

Lee - Give me a sec to upload it

Comment: Thank you for sharing that lee, is there an efficiency to running the Invoke/scriptblock vs the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue that answers your question, the property `DefaultIPGateway` of the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration) is of the type `string[]`:

> **DefaultIPGateway** 
> **Data type**: string array

You need to convert it to `string` so that `Export-Csv` can handle it:

```sh
PS /> @{ Gateway = $computerGateway[0].DefaultIPGateway } | ConvertTo-Csv

"Gateway"
"System.String[]"

PS /> @{ Gateway = [string] $computerGateway[0].DefaultIPGateway } | ConvertTo-Csv

"Gateway"
"192.168.0.1"
```

It is also worth noting that `$computerGateway` may return an array of IPs in which case you should join them:

```sh
$computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway -join ', '
```

Aside from that, there are other issues with your code, for example all Division operations on `$computerHDD`:

```sh
$computerHDD.Size / 1GB
```

**Will throw this exception** if the host has more than one Physical Disk:

> InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because `[System.Object[]]` does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.

`Test-NetConnection` is not reliable to tell you if you can or cannot connect to a remote host, there may be a firewall blocking ICMP packets and you may have been able to still connect it since the protocol being used in your code is WinRM (***WinRM HTTP uses port 5985 and WinRM HTTPS uses port 5986***).

Your code can also be invoked in parallel instead of going one host at a time, `Invoke-Command` is the best alternative as [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) mentions in his helpful comment.

Sending information to the console (`Write-Host`) will only slow your script down, I've removed all instances of console output.

Appending to a file with `Export-Csv -Append` on each iteration of your loop will also slow your script down, the more Disk I/O the slower the code will be, it is better to collect all output first in memory and then writing to a file once.

Lastly, `Get-WmiObject` should be replaced by `Get-CimInstance`. All the WMI Cmdlets are no longer in circulation in newer versions of PowerShell (PowerShell Core). And the CIM Cmdlets have been available since PowerShell 3. **No reason to use WMI over CIM.**

With all that being said, this is how I would approach your script:

```sh
$unavaibleHosts = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$session = foreach($computer in Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users2\101.txt') {
    try {
        New-PSSession $computer -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        $unavaibleHosts.Add($computer)
    }
}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -HideComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    $computerSystem = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem
    $computerBIOS = Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS
    $computerOS = Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem
    $computerCPU = Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor
    $computerHDD = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3
    $computerGateway = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE
    
    $hddSize = $computerHDD.ForEach{ "[{0} {1:N2}]" -f $_.DeviceID, ($_.Size / 1GB) } -join ' | '
    $hddFree = $computerHDD.ForEach{ "[{0} {1:P2}]" -f $_.DeviceID, ($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size) } -join ' | '
    # output from these 2 would look like this:
    # HDDSize      : [C: 236.76] | [D: 931.51]
    # HDDFree      : [C: 73.30%] | [D: 81.43%]
    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name
        'Manufacturer' = $computerSystem.Manufacturer
        'Model' = $computerSystem.Model
        'Service Tag' = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
        'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB)
        'HDDSize' = $hddSize
        'HDDFree' = $hddFree
        'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name
        'OS' = $computerOS.caption
        'SP' = $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
        'User' = $computerSystem.UserName
        'Last_Reboot' = $computerOS.LastBootUpTime
        'Gateway' = $computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway -join ','
    }
} | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId | Export-Csv 'C:\Users2\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Remove-PSSession $session
$unavaibleHosts # => Is here for you to troubleshoot the failed connections.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration
# DefaultIPGateway
# Data type: string array
# Access type: Read-only
# Qualifiers: MappingStrings ("Win32Registry|System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services|Parameters|DefaultGateway")
# Array of IP addresses of default gateways that the computer system uses.
# Example: "192.168.12.1 192.168.46.1"


# Your case
$computerGateway = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer "DESKTOP-9EPNRSP" -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'Gateway' = $computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway
} 
$csvObject.Gateway.GetType().FullName

# Convert to String 
$computerGateway = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer "DESKTOP-9EPNRSP" -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'Gateway' = "$($computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway)"
} 
$csvObject.Gateway.GetType().FullName

#Take first element
$computerGateway = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer "DESKTOP-9EPNRSP" -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'Gateway' = $computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway[0]
} 
$csvObject.Gateway.GetType().FullName

#Generate with comma separated - █ Recommended █
$computerGateway = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer "DESKTOP-9EPNRSP" -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"
$csvObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'Gateway' = [string]::Join(",", $computerGateway.DefaultIPGateway)
} 
$csvObject.Gateway.GetType().FullName
```

**Output**

```
System.String[]
System.String
System.String
System.String
```